# Relating inverse trigonometric functions with $f^{-1}(-x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

Prove that $\arcsin(-x)= -\arcsin x$

Is it mathematically permissible to prove this using semi unit circles?

For example I proved it this way:

Consider the veritcal semi unit circle between y coordinates $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

For $x>0$, $\arcsin (x) = \theta $

From symmetry, $x$ is vertically above $-x$ and there are two congruent triangles with same base. Now, we just need to change the direction to measure the other angle which can be done by placing a minus sign before the first angle obtained.

Thus, $-\arcsin x= \arcsin -x$.

QED

Is this proof fine?

Similarly we can prove (using semi unit circles) identities like: 
$\arccos(-x)= \pi - \arccos(x)$

Comment: It's a bit handwavy.  In general if f is odd and invertible, then f^{-1} is odd as well.  You might just prove that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good but a little vague. Instead of symmetry all you really need to rely on is the fact that $\sin$ is odd. The definition of the $\arcsin$ is that $\theta = \arcsin x$ if and only if $\theta \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and $\sin \theta = x.$ You get
\begin{align*} \theta = \arcsin (-x) &\iff \theta \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2] \text{ and } \sin \theta = -x \\
&\iff - \theta \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2] \text{ and } \sin(-\theta) = x\\
&\iff - \theta = \arcsin x. \end{align*}

Thus $\theta = \arcsin(-x)$ and $-\theta = \arcsin x$ are logically equivalent. You can equate $\theta$ to get the identity you want.

---

**ADDENDUM:** Your question about $\arccos$ has a similar answer. Its definition is that $\theta = \arccos x$ if and only if $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ and $\cos \theta = x$.  Following a similar list of implications using the  identity $\cos (\pi - \theta) = \cos \pi \cos \theta + \sin \pi \sin \theta = -\cos \theta$ you get
\begin{align*}
\theta = \arccos(-x) &\iff \theta \in [0,\pi] \text{ and } \cos \theta = -x \\
&\iff - \theta \in [-\pi,0] \text{ and } -\cos(\theta) = x \\
&\iff \pi - \theta \in [0,\pi] \text{ and } \cos(\pi - \theta) = x\\
&\iff \pi - \theta = \arccos x.
\end{align*}
As above you can equate $\theta$ to find $\pi - \arccos(-x) = \arccos x$.